# How to find a path from source to target with obstacle avoidance

Tags: c#, robotics

Actually my robot wants to move from source to target with obstacle avoidance. I find out the obstacle(rectangle shape) and Target(circle shape) in pixels. But i don't know how to find the path from source to target... Please help me.

Here is the code for finding obstacle and target.

```
for (int i = 0, n = blobs.Length; i < n; i++)
               {
                   List<IntPoint> edgePoints = blobCounter.GetBlobsEdgePoints(blobs[i]);

                   AForge.Point center;
                   float radius;

                   // is circle ?
                   if (shapeChecker.IsCircle(edgePoints, out center, out radius))
                   {
                       g.DrawEllipse(whitePen, (float)(center.X - radius), (float)(center.Y - radius),
                                    (float)(radius * 2), (float)(radius * 2));
                       target.Add(center.ToString());
                   }
                   else
                   {
                       List<IntPoint> corners;
                       // is triangle or quadrilateral
                       if (shapeChecker.IsConvexPolygon(edgePoints, out corners))
                       {
                           // get sub-type
                           PolygonSubType subType = shapeChecker.CheckPolygonSubType(corners);
                           Pen pen;

                           if (subType == PolygonSubType.Unknown)
                           {
                               pen = (corners.Count == 4) ? redPen : bluePen;
                           }
                           else
                           {
                               pen = (corners.Count == 4) ? greenPen : brownPen;
                           }
                           g.DrawPolygon(pen, ToPointsArray(corners));
                       }
                   }
               }
```

This above coding will detect obstacle and target position pixel values and store it in a seperate array. But from these pixel values how to calculate the path? Waiting for ur suggestions.....

Answer (score 1):

Trying looking up the A* search algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

I have not looked into your code but it is a classic path finding problem. One suggestion could be to map the entire area the robot moves onto a grid. The grid can have discrete cells. And then you can use any graph search algorithm to find a path from start cell to goal cell.

You can use few of the algorithms, like Dijkistra, Best-first and A-Star search algorithms. It turns out that A-Star is efficient and easy to implement. Check [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20171022224528/http://www.policyalmanac.org:80/games/aStarTutorial.htm), contains a nice explanation about A-Star.